# Expression for .NET statements

Tags: c#, .net, regex, editor

I want to implement an online editor for my *personal* usages, so that I have to **check that the statements** which I write in my online text editor are in **right form or not**.

I want to check the form of statements with regular expressions, I found a good expression for **IF statement** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651455/regular-expression-to-identify-if-statements) and it is

```
if\s*\(((?:(?:(?:"(?:(?:\\")|[^"])*")|(?:'(?:(?:\\')|[^'])*'))|[^\(\)]|\((?1)\))*+)\)\s*{((?:(?:(?:"(?:(?:\\")|[^"])*")|(?:'(?:(?:\\')|[^'])*'))|[^{}]|{(?2)})*+)}\s*(?:(?:else\s*{((?:(?:(?:"(?:(?:\\")|[^"])*")|(?:'(?:(?:\\')|[^'])*'))|[^{}]|{(?3)})*+)}\s*)|(?:else\s*if\s*\(((?:(?:(?:"(?:(?:\\")|[^"])*")|(?:'(?:(?:\\')|[^'])*'))|[^\(\)]|\((?4)\))*+)\)\s*{((?:(?:(?:"(?:(?:\\")|[^"])*")|(?:'(?:(?:\\')|[^'])*'))|[^{}]|{(?5)})*+)}\s*))*;
```

Now I'm looking for the rest of expression e.g:

- for
- while
- variable definition (like : int xxx string xxx)
- switch case
- new (object : class, enum)
- foreach

Please `don't say that it's impossible`, I can handle my problem with `regular expression` and `IF expression` I mentioned above is **working great** and I need such a thing for the rest

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wow, that's one large list of characters :P

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible, but I'd say that lexical parsing is often done with FSMs (manually) or some 3rd party software that can create AST using your grammatics (like ANTLR).

Comment: I highly doubt that the regular expression is 100% accurate. Regular expressions simply aren't a good match for this problem if you want decent accuracy, IMO.

Comment: Indeed. C# has a very complex grammar, you'd be much better off with a BNF grammar-based parser generator such as Gold Parser. This can generate a parser in C# for any regular grammar you define. I've used it to parse 2 languages myself with great results.

Comment: @Zerkms, Can you give me an example?

Comment: An impressive regex that you have found. Have you understood it?

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list -- there are a lot of grammars, including several c# ones.

Comment: @Jon, I don't need 100% accuracy because it is not an official project and I want to use it for some academic reasons. If you know a good regular expression for a statement let me know

Comment: @stema, it's not important for me understand them to completely, I got 80% of it and that's enough I don't want to edit or expand them for now, after a while I'll check them all

Answer (score 5):

Even though this is not a direct answer to your question - I'm *insisting* you to use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) instead

Comment: I download the Project for C# 4.0 Compiler, now how can I use it?

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo: sorry for being obvious, but you can start using it from reading the documentation.

Comment: I asked because as in Codeplex mentioned, there is no documentation for it yet. You can check it here : [http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/documentation ]

Comment: @Nasser Hadjloo: :-S did not even know that. I just have taken it and work, without and c#-specific documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use in this case regular expressions,  you should use something like 
syntax analyzer

Answer (score 0):

My experience with using regular expressions for parsing is they are only practical if:

- You are willing to write and maintain them yourself
- You can accept that they aren't rigorously correct

Since you are asking for help you probably don't meet the first criterion and so I cannot recommend them for you.

P.S.  Yes, I sometimes do use them myself in quick-and-dirty parsing situations.  They are invaluable.